# How to make Ubuntu not to lock the screen while running VMware in fullscreen?

Tags: 12.04, vmware, screensaver, lock-screen, fullscreen

I am running Windows XP inside VMware Player. I have two monitors and I keep VMware in fullscreen on the second monitor.

The problem is that if I work long enough in inside Windows XP, Ubuntu locks the screen as if I was idle. Once that happens I need to enter my password in order to return to the desktop on the other monitor.

Is there a way to fix or workaround this problem without disabling screensaver lock in Ubuntu temporarily or permanently?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this. If so, could you please post it here - Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I think installing Caffeine could help you. It's a nice application which blocks your PC from going to suspend/lock-screen/black-screen when selected applications are running.

You can install it like this (available for precise):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install caffeine
```

After that just run the program. You will have a little indicator of a coffee mug in your panel.

[image]

[image]

You can manually activate Caffeine by clicking on the indicator and selecting "Deactivate screensaver" or you go to Preferences and select the applications for which it should activate itself automatically. It's also great for video players or Flash videos.

[image]

You can also read all about it [on OMG!ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/06/how-do-you-use-caffeine-the-app-not-the-stimulant/).

Comment: While this is a good workaround that I was aware of it doesn't help the issue. It falls under "temporarily disabling locking" Still - upvoting because someone else might find it helpful. :)