# Which ubuntu application is responsible for dimming the screen when its going to lock?

Tags: screen, source-code

I want to write a custom application which can dim my screen. I like the default effect of dimming the screen in Ubuntu when system it's not in use for 10 minutes (default setting). Which program or code in kernel is responsible for this effect?

Comment: gnome-power manager (assuming you are using gnome). See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/234689/cannot-permanently-prevent-power-saving-blank-screen-on-compaq-presario-c700-wit and http://askubuntu.com/questions/216783/ubuntu-12-10-turn-screen-off-when-inactive-for-never-still-turns-off

Comment: system settings --> lock screen --> disable dim screen after X minutes.

Comment: @Alvar Are you kidding me? Where did I asked about how to disable dim... Read question first.

Comment: you know your question have a title right?

Comment: Yes, I do. And I was asking which application is responsible for dim effect, NOT HOW TO ENABLE/DISABLE DIMMING. gnome-power-manager is what I was looking for.